# Ansible Openstack get/update application credentials

Tags: ansible, openstack, ansible-playbook

I'm trying to fetch and update application credentials through Ansible [`openstack.cloud`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/openstack/cloud/index.html) module, but I cannot find any information about that. Is it possible to use Ansible to list my own application credentials and create a new one?

I tried also with the `openstack.cloud.resource`, but the `openstacksdk` proxy goes into an error:

source code:

```
- name: Test
  openstack.cloud.resource:
    cloud: openstack
    service: identity
    type: application_credential
    attributes:
      user: myuser
      name: app_cred_name
  register: app_cred_data
```

error:

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: AttributeError: 'Proxy' object has no attribute 'update_application_credential'. Did you mean: 'create_application_credential'?
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/home/vscode/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1695798933.7218165-40585-211051185410492/AnsiballZ_resource.py\", line 107, in <module>\n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/home/vscode/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1695798933.7218165-40585-211051185410492/AnsiballZ_resource.py\", line 99, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/home/vscode/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1695798933.7218165-40585-211051185410492/AnsiballZ_resource.py\", line 47, in invoke_module\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible_collections.openstack.cloud.plugins.modules.resource', init_globals=dict(_module_fqn='ansible_collections.openstack.cloud.plugins.modules.resource', _modlib_path=modlib_path),\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py\", line 224, in run_module\n    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py\", line 96, in _run_module_code\n    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py\", line 86, in _run_code\n    exec(code, run_globals)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_openstack.cloud.resource_payload_8dl_iu61/ansible_openstack.cloud.resource_payload.zip/ansible_collections/openstack/cloud/plugins/modules/resource.py\", line 425, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_openstack.cloud.resource_payload_8dl_iu61/ansible_openstack.cloud.resource_payload.zip/ansible_collections/openstack/cloud/plugins/modules/resource.py\", line 421, in main\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_openstack.cloud.resource_payload_8dl_iu61/ansible_openstack.cloud.resource_payload.zip/ansible_collections/openstack/cloud/plugins/module_utils/openstack.py\", line 415, in __call__\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_openstack.cloud.resource_payload_8dl_iu61/ansible_openstack.cloud.resource_payload.zip/ansible_collections/openstack/cloud/plugins/modules/resource.py\", line 400, in run\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_openstack.cloud.resource_payload_8dl_iu61/ansible_openstack.cloud.resource_payload.zip/ansible_collections/openstack/cloud/plugins/module_utils/resource.py\", line 43, in __init__\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_openstack.cloud.resource_payload_8dl_iu61/ansible_openstack.cloud.resource_payload.zip/ansible_collections/openstack/cloud/plugins/module_utils/resource.py\", line 19, in default_crud_functions\nAttributeError: 'Proxy' object has no attribute 'update_application_credential'. Did you mean: 'create_application_credential'?\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this and I agree it doesn't work. Application credentials are immutable so there is no update method. Also the get/find methods have an extra user argument which won't work with the `openstack.cloud.resource` model. I intend to propose a new `application_credential` module.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/576508)